# BelongsTo return class

Tags: php, laravel

When I use belongsTo without default keys it won't connect..

My users table has `user_id` which is some rand and unique string that presents that user. My urls table has `user_id` and `uri` columns where `user_id` contains `users` table `user_id`.

In Url model I have:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','user_id');
}
```

In User model I have:

```
public function uri() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Url', 'user_id', 'user_id')->first()->uri;
}
```

By using `$user->uri()` I get `uri` from `urls` table connected with `user_id`.

But when I use `$url->user()` I get return null or BelongsTo class inside laravel tinker.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User::uri()` method is not a relationship method.

You are utilizing a relationship method inside of it, but you are querying it for the first result and returning the uri property.

Your `Url::user()` method IS a relationship method because you are actually returning a relationship (BelongsTo) instance.  Eloquent relationships are used as follows:

```
// To get a related entity on a BelongsTo relationship, you access it as a property:
$url->user

// To query a relationship, you use it as a method:
$url->user()->where(...)->first();
```

Comment: I have another question, I used same approach for avatar() method and I tried as you said it did not work unless I added ->first() ... is it because I didnt add anything to avatar model and do I need to add to avatar model belongsTo as well to make relationship?

Comment: What type of relationship?  For HasOne or BelongsTo, $model->relation should be equivalent to $model->relation()->first().

Comment: So if the model is $user, `$user->avatar` is how you'd access the avatar if you're returning a relationship instance.  There's never a need to use `first()` with HasOne.

Comment: I made a new app and copied everything I needed there and now it works as you say, I dont know why but it does :D